# Could not run xamarin application with SQLite.NET-PCL on iPad

Tags: c#, ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios, cross-platform

I have created an new application with a simple test which works fine every time with iOSSimulator, but doesnt work when i try to run on my iPad. On my application, i only have the SQLite.NET-PCL 3.1.1 installed by nuget and my controller only makes a call to create a database.

When a try on iPad, the console give me the following error:

```
MTOUCH: error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/delogic/Projects/iosSingleView/iosSingleView/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-ipad3.1-9.3.2/mtouch-cache/Build/SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinIOS.Unified.dll'
```

The following lines on the log caught my attention:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
      "_sqlite3_busy_timeout", referenced from:
          wrapper_managed_to_native_SQLite_Net_Platform_XamarinIOS_SQLiteApiIOSInternal_sqlite3_busy_timeout_intptr_int in SQLite-5f40c7.o
      "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
          wrapper_managed_to_native_SQLite_Net_Platform_XamarinIOS_SQLiteApiIOSInternal_sqlite3_close_intptr in SQLite-5f40c7.o
      "_sqlite3_errmsg16", referenced from:
          wrapper_managed_to_native_SQLite_Net_Platform_XamarinIOS_SQLiteApiIOSInternal_sqlite3_errmsg16_intptr in SQLite-5f40c7.o
      "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
          wrapper_managed_to_native_SQLite_Net_Platform_XamarinIOS_SQLiteApiIOSInternal_sqlite3_finalize_intptr in SQLite-5f40c7.o
      "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
          wrapper_managed_to_native_SQLite_Net_Platform_XamarinIOS_SQLiteApiIOSInternal_sqlite3_open_v2_byte___intptr__int_intptr in SQLite-5f40c7.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I guess which for some reason, my file is missing some methods.Does anyone have the same problem? i will upload the project sample and the full log.

[link for log and project download](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/0B05AavSPQyF2UDZvTVFOaVhhQzg)

Answer (score 0):

i got this resolved. Its was a bug on xamarin studio which got fixed when i choosed the update channel to alpha